# I am not seeing Management Folder in SSAS but I do see it in SSMS. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssas

So I am trying to turn on extended events for my SSAS multidimensional cube. However, when I am logged into SSAS (with full admin priv) I only see Database & Assembly folders as seen below.

[image]

I am following Microsoft's guide online for this from the following link:
[Monitor Analysis Services with Extended Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/monitor-analysis-services-with-sql-server-extended-events?view=asallproducts-allversions)

They show the following options under Microsoft Analysis Sevices in this guide as can be seen below:

> [image]

Any help would be appreciated as I really want to use this data.

Comment: The cube is using 2012.

Comment: I am using SSMS 2018. My apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Always nice to be schooled lol....I am using version 15.0.18330.0

Comment: The documentation you linked *might* imply there is no UI support for this until MSSQL 2016 even if using the newest SSMS...but I am not 100% sure. You should still be able to use EE via T-SQL though

Comment: @LowlyDBA Thank you for that nugget. I will look into doing this with T-SQL in the meantime. If you have any useful links on how to do this I would appreciate it.